# If itachi was resurrected again would he have both eyes and full sight in both since the caster decides when they come back as

Tags: naruto

Since the person will be revived as any part of their life (for example madara was brought back as in his prime instead of old) and madara did lose his sight in eye due to izanami, but has both eyes when revived, if itachi were to be resurrected again would he have both of his eyes with light and full sight or would he still have no light in one of his eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Edo Tensei gives you new fake eyes. Thats why Madara's Edo eyes faded away after he was completely made alive with Rinne Tensei.

[image]

Unless Itachi is revived by Rinne Tensei, he will be resurrected again with his eyes intact.